# How can one relate two objects in java?

Tags: java, object

What I would like to know is how one can set an object to react in a certain way to another specific object.

For example: There could be a class called `swordInStone` and it only reacts when someone from the class `royalty` tries to grab it. IE:

```
public class swordInStone{
    if(swordHilt.isPulledBy(royalty.grab)){
    releaseSword();
    }
}
```

but in the example code, `royalty` would have to be a named and active object, such as `Arthur`. I would like to be able to replace it with any object from the `class` `royalty`

Comment: Try with inheritance,

Comment: @user3717646 could you be slightly more descriptive please, I don't know what you mean by that.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with type checking:

```
public class Royalty {}

public class Sword {
    private Stone stone;

    public Sword(Stone stone) {
        this.stone = stone;
    }

    public void grab(Object grabber) {
        if (grabber instanceof Royalty)
            stone.releaseSword();
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably mean: `grabber.releaseSword();` ;)

Comment: @alfasin well, probably we need a `Stone` class, and have the sword tell the stone to release it. Or perhaps it isn't the sword that knows who is royalty or not, and the sword just passes the grabber onto the stone to determine whether to release the sword or not!  We really need to define the responsibilities of these classes!

Comment: What would happen if the grabber is a subclass of Royalty?

Comment: @alfasin ah, you can see that the OP's `swordInStone` class is actually a conflation of the two concepts.  Not very good [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) at all!

Comment: @user3717646 it is still considered as royalty (like in real life ;)

Comment: @user3717646 `instanceof` checks if the instance is in the inheritance hierarchy of the type, so it will work just the same

Comment: @JamieCockburn indeed, it would be better to have `Stone` class to do it, but anyways, the idea is that `releaseSword()` is a "callback" - not a method of class `Sword`

Comment: @alfasin You reckon? I assumed that it was the instruction to the stone to release the sword from it's magical grip.

Comment: @JamieCockburn you got it - and that's exactly why `releaseSword()` is a callback - the sword cannot release itself...

Comment: @alfasin but it's not calling back to the person who grabbed it, only the stone can effect the release of the sword.

Comment: @JamieCockburn a callback in the meaning that it calls somebody else to do the action - it's not being done by `this`. I edited a small addition just to toy with the idea and add some DI to the cauldron.

Comment: @alfasin Well, now you've confused matter, of course, at the point that sword was forged, it wasn't embedded into the stone!  I was assuming the `stone` was set magically, by Merlin, when he struck it into the stone in the first place.

Comment: @JamieCockburn +1 to that, now reverse all your answer and create `sword` as a private member of `stone` instead :D

Comment: @alfasin that would be a little tricky in pure Java, maybe AspectJ would be the way to model just magic?